# Is violin string core a "piano wire"?

Tags: material-science, string

I'm planning to use a violin string core as a material for torsion wire. Is it safe to assume that a violin string core (steel) is similar to what is called "piano wire" or "music wire"? Is it generally lower or higher quality? I'm confused about how wide is a definition of "piano wire" and what exactly makes this definition.

Properties of interest:

1. Has no twist
2. Tensile strength
3. Toughness

What I was reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_wire

http://www.engineeringenotes.com/metallurgy/steel/heat-treatment-of-spring-steels-metallurgy/26992

Citations:

"The music-wire spring steel is about the best, toughest and most widely used for all types of small springs subjected to high stresses, frequent deflections and suddenly applied loads"

and

"It is recommended for small helical and torsion springs"

Comment: Normally, violin strings are not made of metal but of kattgut. (No, not real cats, I think...) Try strings for electric guitars.

Comment: Well, yes I know, but these days steel core is a popular material and I'm talking about these. Usually E string is a bare steel. G D A is a steel core wraped with some other metal.

Comment: @Pieter Violin strings can certainly be made from steel or synthetic Perlon, and in fact it's fairly common for strings to at least have steel cores. And catgut is usually sheep or goat intestines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to a music store, they can sell you a single electric guitar string with no wraps (called a "plain" string) in a diameter ranging from 0.008" to 0.022" in 0.002" increments. It will cost a dollar or two. These are made from hard-drawn *music wire*.

Comment: I observed violin steel core and accoustic guitar steel core under microscope. Violin core looked noticeably more smooth surface. So I desided that it is a better candidate. Maybe I just have low quality guitar strings on my hands, I dont know. I just wanted confirmation about what is defined as a music wire, and is violin string core a "music wire".

Comment: guitar strings corrode fairly fast on exposure to hand sweat. Try a fresh new string straight from the package.

Comment: Thats a fair observation. Thank you. Yet, I always saw violin as more precise and delicate instrument. So I was from start considering to use violin string if it is actually comparable to music wire steel qualities. That is why I'm posting this question.